# Rename sheet based on data connection contained in the sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have 100 .txt files. Each .txt is connected to a different sheet in the workbook. I would like to name the sheet based on the name of .txt file connected in that sheet.

Here are some code. 
Unfortunately they do not work as I got the error: "name already taken"

```
    Sub MultipleTextFilesIntoExcelSheets()
Dim i As Integer 'a counter to loop through the files in the folder
Dim fname As String, FullName As String 'fname is the name of the file, and FullName is the name of its path
Dim ws As Worksheet 'a workbook object for the workbook where the current macro is running


''' Delete existing data connections
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Do While ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count > 0
ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count).Delete
Loop


''' Rename raw data sheets to default string
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
i = 1

For Each ws In Worksheets
If ws.Name Like "Test1" Or ws.Name Like "Test2*" = True Then
'Do Nothing
ElseIf ws.Name Like "Test1" Or ws.Name Like "Test2*" = False Then
ws.Name = "Sheet" & i
i = i + 1 'get ready for the next iteration
End If
Next ws


''' Import .txt files
'''''''''''''''''''''
i = 0

'get the name of the first text file
fname = Dir("C:\Sample\Test\*txt")

'loop through the text files to put them onto separate sheets in the Excel book
While (Len(fname) > 0)
'get the full path of the text file
FullName = "C:\Sample\Test\" & fname
i = i + 1  'get ready for the next iteration

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & i) 'the current sheet

With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & FullName, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
    .Name = fname
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True    'we are using a tab-delimited file
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileOtherDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    fname = Dir
End With
Wend


''' Rename sheets to new string
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
For Each ws In Worksheets
If ws.Name Like "Test1" Or ws.Name Like "Test2*" = True Then
'Do Nothing

ElseIf (ws.Name Like "Test1" Or ws.Name Like "Test2*" = False) Then
ws.Name = Left(fname, (Len(fname) - 4))
End If

Next ws
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance,
Fede

Comment: what do you mean by connected to each worksheet? how are they connected?

Comment: .txt files have been connected using the "data" ribbon --> "from text". Hope this clarifies. Thank you.

Comment: and what was the process you used to import the text files? did you do this manually? or was the done by vba?

Comment: Change fname = Dir("C:\test\*txt") to fname = Dir("C:\test\*.txt")

Answer (score 0):

You use `Dir` once to put an initial value into `fname` but then never change this initial value. In the second pass through the loop you are still using the same fname, hence Excel complains that you are using a name that is already taken.

It *might* work to insert the line `fname = Dir` right before `Next ws`. This would seem to be what you want, though I am uncomfortable with the overall logic of your code since it isn't clear how it guarantees that the right name goes with the right sheet. It might make more sense to write a sub that starts with an initially empty workbook and iterates through the folder importing the data and naming the sheets in one pass.

Also -- I think the logic of your `ElseIf` is murky. For one thing -- why not a simple `Else`?

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your answer. fname = Dir right before does not work: "Invalid procedure call". Moreover, to answer your comment about my coding: I need some coding that attaches the .txt file name to the sheet name. Not interested in the 'right name goes with the right sheet' as I'm inserting the sheet name after the data connection is established. Hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe combine it with MatthewD's suggestion. It looks like your initial Dir has a problem.

Comment: Still error. Should I use a while loop? I mean, how can I ask vba to take the second .txt for sheet, the third .txt for sheet3 etc? Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you are running out of files before you are running out of sheets. The typical idiom when using Dir is to test its return on each pass through the loop and terminate when empty. You should test its value. You could refactor the code to a while loop -- or test and Exit the for loop early if you need. It wouldn't hurt to put a simple `Debug.Print fname` at the top of the loop and see what you get.

Comment: Can I kindly ask you to help me setting up the loop? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you will need to move the renaming of the sheets into your while loop prior to updating fname. (Update the sheet when you already know which sheet needs to be renamed)